# Kotlin: Dependency injection of generic JsonAdapter using Moshi and Hilt

Tags: kotlin, moshi, dagger-hilt

I have an Android app which uses Hilt for dependency injection, and Moshi for JSON parsing. The app makes http-requests to a REST server which returns a json response with the following format for all endpoints returning data:

```
{ 
   data: specificData,
   errors: [...]
}
```

I want to provide a generic json adapter which can be injected into DataSource classes like this:

```
class LoginDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    private val authAdapter: JsonAdapter<NetworkResponse<Auth>>
)
```

with the following data classes for example:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class NetworkResponse<T> (val data: T, val errors: Array<Int>)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Auth (val token: String, val refreshToken: String)
```

Searching for a way to provide the json adapter I ended up creating the following Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object MoshiAdapterModule {

    @Provides
    inline fun <reified T> provideGenericNetworkResponseJsonAdapter(): JsonAdapter<NetworkResponse<T>> {
        val typeT: Type = Types.newParameterizedType(NetworkResponse::class.java,  T::class.java)
        val moshi =  Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
        return moshi.adapter(typeT)
    }
}
```

However, this did not work and I get an [Dagger/MissingBinding] error telling me that `JsonAdapter<NetworkResponse<Auth>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method`. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I recently started learning Kotlin, and haven't used Hilt or Moshi before, so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I don't think you can use generics at all, how should Hilt know what to inject in these?